# Surprisingly low accuracy using tesseract for OCR recognition on simple images. How can I improve it?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract to parse digits extracted from browser screenshots. This is my first experience with OCR, please correct me if I'm going at this the wrong way. I get very low accuracy on images that look easily interpretable to me. Sometimes I get empty string; rarely I also get wrong digits.

Elsewhere, people suggested filtering and enlarging the image. I did so and it made it better, going from accuracy of almost 0 to around 50%, but that's still poor. I am working on a selenium-extracted screenshot; some code is reported below. Sorry if it's messy, I included the image loading and processing part to show what I was doing but didn't want to give away the page I'm loading.

Here is an image in which I show what the images look like after processing, and the result of parsing and converting to float.

[image: What my images and output look like]

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, cv2, time, numpy as np

# load the page, enlarge, save as png, load as usable image
driver.get("https://a-page-I-wont-tell-you-sorry")
time.sleep(5) # wait for loading
driver.execute_script('document.body.style.MozTransform = "scale(1.50)";') # enlarge
enlarged_screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
file = open("enlarged_screenshot.png", "wb")
file.write(enlarged_screenshot)
file.close()
enlarged_screenshot = Image.open("enlarged_screenshot.png")

# method for cropping and filtering
def crop_and_filter(image, coordinates, filter_level):
    width, height = image.size
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = coordinates
    cropped_image = image.crop((width*x0, height*y0, width*x1, height*y1))
    image_l = cropped_image.convert("L")
    image_array = np.array(image_l)
    _, filtered_image_array = cv2.threshold(image_array, filter_level, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)    

    print("*"*100); print("Filtered image:")
    display(Image.fromarray(filtered_image_array))

    return filtered_image_array

# example of how I call and parse it
x0 = 0.51; y0 = 0.43; delta_x = 0.05; delta_y = 0.025
filtered_image_array = crop_and_filter(enlarged_screenshot, (x0, y0, x0+delta_x, y0+delta_y), 125, True)
number = pytesseract.image_to_string(filtered_image_array, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.\t%")
```

Comment: It's really really hard to diagnose without a specific input image - otherwise you will invite only general comments e.g. "Do some preprocessing". Can you put up a sample image even if it's not the real one? That's also a good way to help you figure out what's going on/wrong. FWIW: I wonder if your open/imread is mangling the png. Also, do you need PIL AND OpenCV? How are you quantifying / measuring defining accuracy?

Comment: Thank you for answering. There is an image in the link above with 8 post processing images, I thought that'd be useful. I will put a link to the original picture later tonight. I had never heard of PIL, openCV nor tesseract until 2 days ago, I just put this together copying snippets from the web, feel free to tell me what's the sane way to do this :). In terms of quantifying accuracy, I ran this for about 20 numbers and got about 10 correct reads so I said around 50%. Whether it's 40% or 60% doesn't really make a big difference for me, I'd need 90% at least.

Comment: Ah OK - first I thought that was your image, so I ran a test and got decent results, but then I thought in fact your image was _of_ the results, so I undid everything. Just tell me how you would like to measure accuracy (can you post a ground-truth text file, for example?) and I'll post an answer (for Tesseract not pytesseract - unless you insist on the latter?)

Comment: Thank you, what is a ground truth text file? Could you give me some instructions on using tesseract instead of pytesseract? This code will be part of a running python script. (I'll post anything you ask me for tonight as I don't have access to my computer till then)

Comment: Look at https://pastebin.com/i6W9k9Nv - that's the output I got - is it good enough?

Comment: ground truth = the answer you expect to get (the "truth"), so you can see what you measure from the data and use the difference between the two to measure some (somehow-defined) accuracy

Comment: Well yeah you get all the numbers right so of course it's good enough on this set :) Could I ask you what code you used?

Comment: OK cool - I'll add an answer below then you can comment on it, if and where it is lacking

Answer (score 0):

*This started as, but was too long for, a comment:*

Your question was slightly unclear but in the end I figured you wanted to run Tesseract over the actual image you posted at https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5WJQ.png

The command I used was

```
tesseract --oem 1 -l eng --psm 11 m5WJQ.png stdout
```

This produced the following output:

```
ek ok ek ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok

Filtered image:

65

HAA

Filtered image:

3

HAA

Filtered image:

3.5

HAA

Filtered image:

2.64

HAA

Filtered image:

75

HAA

Filtered image:

3.1

HAA

Filtered image:

3.6

HAA

Filtered image:

2.68

EARSED NUMBERS:

[nan, nan,

3.5, 2.64, nan,

3.1, 3.6, 2.68]
```

As per your comments on your original question, this looks good to you.

I am running Tesseract on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra built from source (but you don't have to do this).

```
tesseract --version
tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-371-ga9227
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.0.10 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.0.3 : libopenjp2 2.3.1
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.4.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.4 bz2lib/1.0.6
```

See if you can also reproduce this and comment if you can't. I will see if I can get the corresponding output from pytesseract.

Also, since you (sometimes) know what the numbers should be, you can use tools like ocreval (https://github.com/eddieantonio/ocreval - I'm not affiliated with it) to see how well your run is doing compared to the known/input/"ground" truth.

HTH

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I have run my pytesseract command on the same image I used to generate the output above, but cropped via paint instead of image.crop, and got pretty much perfect output this time (except for a "£111" which became a "fill", but that is understandable.). I think I should just experiment with this a bit more and hopefully it'll be fine. If I struggle again I'll comment again so you get a notification and I'll post a completely reproducible example to make it easier to help me. If not I'll accept your post as answer in a few days.